# How to align one item to the right In React Bootstrap 5

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align an item called Login to the right of the NavBar. How should I do it? Thanks

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Nav, Navbar, NavLink}  from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigationbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="sm" bg="primary" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='navbarScroll' data-bs-target="#navbarScroll"/>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
          <Nav>
            <NavLink href="/">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink href="/about">About</NavLink>
            <NavLink href="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
           ** <NavLink style={{justifyContent:"flex-end"}}>Login</NavLink>**
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navigationbar
```

I tried using tyle={{justifyContent:"flex-end"}} and is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `<Nav>` full width and then apply `margin-left: auto` to the link:

```js
const { Container, Nav, Navbar, NavLink } = ReactBootstrap;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <div>
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="sm" bg="primary" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='navbarScroll' data-bs-target="#navbarScroll"/>
      <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
        <Nav style={{ width: '100%' }}>
          <NavLink href="/">Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink href="/about">About</NavLink>
          <NavLink href="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
          <NavLink className="ms-auto">Login</NavLink>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </div>
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/2.8.0/react-bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-hSAnp8t2uUf7f1vHEtw6AfJisBLZEC61Aqrz6MZtf0J5iZn+9DYctEdqRxHd09jjFC16n2LvpRFcp7iYmrPZcw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="app"></div>
```